# How to get values from a databound listbox's selected items parsed by json into various textboxes

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, winforms

Quite new to programing overall so please try to keep it simple as i might not understand.
Also english isn't my native language.

My goal is to display in few textboxes different values that i got from a json deserialized string, i already have this string as "data source" for a listbox, now i want to click the button "load manga" and make it so that the textboxes get the corresponding values from the selected listbox item, however all i'm being able to do so far is fill the "comic" textbox.
My question is how exactly do i do this?
This gets the text from the selected item of the listbox into the textbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //name of comic
    comicName_txtbx.Text = Convert.ToString(Manga_listBox.GetItemText(Manga_listBox.SelectedItem));
}
```

so what do i need to add to that to populate this ?:
ComicTotalCHs_txtbx.Text is suposed to take the values that should be in "chapters"

```
//total chapters of comic
ComicTotalCHs_lbl.Text = "";
ComicTotalCHs_txtbx.Text = "";
```

I also have the following classes for reference:

```
public class Comic
{
    private string manga;
    private int chapters;
    private bool isFinished;
    private int lastReadCH;

    public string Manga { get => manga; set => manga = value; }
    public int Chapters { get => chapters; set => chapters = value; }
    public bool IsFinished { get => isFinished; set => isFinished = value; }
    public int LastReadCH { get => lastReadCH; set => lastReadCH = value; }
}
```

```
public class ComicList
{
    private List<Comic> comics;

    public List<Comic> Comics { get => comics; set => comics = value; }
}
```

```
public class DisplayComic
{
    private static List<Comic> fullList;

    public static List<Comic> FullList { get => fullList; set => fullList = value; }

    public static List<Comic> GetComcis()
    {
        return FullList;
    }
}
```

By the way this is how I'm getting that json string:

```
var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    ComicList comics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ComicList>(fileContent);
    DisplayComic.FullList = comics.Comics;
    Manga_listBox.DataSource = DisplayComic.FullList;
    Manga_listBox.DisplayMember = "manga";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so someone sent me this on a irc chatroom:
((List)listBox.DataSource)[3].SomeProperty
it works flawlessly just by adding

ComicTotalCHs_txtbx.Text = Convert.ToString(((List)Manga_listBox.DataSource)[Convert.ToInt32(Manga_listBox.SelectedIndex)].Chapters);

there it is